# Two consecutive uppercase letters from the end

Tags: regex, stata

I want a regular expression that will help me extract a person's name from a string using Stata.

Examples of the strings are as follows:

```
name_adr
JAMES DeNORMANDIETrapelo Rd., Lincoln
JAMES A. KELLY, JR.Stafford St., Oxford
GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCKMt. Lebanon St., Pepperell
```

What I went to get out of them is below:

```
name
JAMES DeNORMANDIE
JAMES A. KELLY, JR.
GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCK
```

The tricky part is that some of the names have non-capitalized bits.

My idea was to look for the part of the string where there are two consecutive capital letters from the back. The simple regular expression I used was `[A-Z][A-Z][.*]$`, but even this does not work.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Take a look at this regex:**

```
.+(?=(?:[A-Z]{2})|_)(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]\.)?)?
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6oAZ8D/3)

**Output:**

> - JAMES DeNORMANDIE
> - JAMES A. KELLY, JR.
> - GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCK

**Explanation:**

```
.+                      # Match all characters
(?=[A-Z]{2}|_)          # Positive lookahead - assert that matches two capitals or _ (but does not capture)
(?:                     # Non-capturing group
  (?:[A-Z])             # Match one capital letter
  (?:[A-Z]\.)?          # Optionally match one capital letter followed by dot
)?                      # Non-capturing group is optional
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Data example as Stata code:

```
clear
input str49 name_adr
"JAMES DeNORMANDIETrapelo Rd., Lincoln"            
"JAMES A. KELLY, JR.Stafford St., Oxford"          
"GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCKMt. Lebanon St., Pepperell"
end
```

This is @Emma's approach:

```
local regex ^((?:[A-Z]+\s+){1,2}(?:[A-Z]\.\s*)*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]|^((?:[A-Z]+\s+){1,2}(?:[A-Z]\.\s*)*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[A-Z]\s*,\s*JR.)

generate name = ustrregexs(1) + ustrregexs(2) if ustrregexm(name_adr, "`regex'")

     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                                          name_adr                      name |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |             JAMES DeNORMANDIETrapelo Rd., Lincoln         JAMES DeNORMANDIE |
  2. |           JAMES A. KELLY, JR.Stafford St., Oxford       JAMES A. KELLY, JR. |
  3. | GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCKMt. Lebanon St., Pepperell   GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCK |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is @vs97's approach:

```
local regex .+(?=(?:[A-Z]{2})|_)(?:(?:[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]\.)?)?

generate name = ustrregexs(0) if ustrregexm(name_adr, "`regex'")

list 
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                                          name_adr                      name |
     |-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |             JAMES DeNORMANDIETrapelo Rd., Lincoln         JAMES DeNORMANDIE |
  2. |           JAMES A. KELLY, JR.Stafford St., Oxford       JAMES A. KELLY, JR. |
  3. | GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCKMt. Lebanon St., Pepperell   GEORGE WILLIAM SHATTUCK |
     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I implemented the suggested solutions in Stata but you should accept one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty complicated, yet maybe it would be OK to try multiple expressions on a case-by-case basis and use alternation maybe, such as with:

```
^((?:[A-Z]+\s+){1,2}(?:[A-Z]\.\s*)*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]|^((?:[A-Z]+\s+){1,2}(?:[A-Z]\.\s*)*[A-Z][A-Za-z]*[A-Z]\s*,\s*JR\.)
```

and the desired outputs are in the capturing groups one and two, as you can see [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58260830/6553328).

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xKY7Kt/1/)

This would make it simple to code, as new cases would come up, you would know which portion of the expression you would want to change or modify. It would only make your expression long, but that would be OK, especially if you would like to have a better accuracy.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/xKY7Kt/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/xKY7Kt/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the excellent answers above, I came up with another solution that simply looks for two consecutive capital letters going from the back. In case this will come helpful to anybody else:

```
gen name = strreverse(regexs(0)) if regexm(strreverse(name_adr), "([\.]*[A-Z][A-Z])(.*)")
replace name = substr(name, 1, strlen(name)-1) if substr(name, -3, .)!="JR."
```